# How to view error when failing to connect to S3 in swift

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 using Swift but I'm not able to establish a connection.  How can I view the error details from S3 to figure out why my upload attempt isn't working.

The parameters I'm passing to S3:

```
["X-Amz-Date": 20160916T010311Z, 
 "X-Amz-Signature":qr647bMEA9M8LeBVqkJLcvEIO4g=, 
 "trackURL": https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/fileID, 
 "key": Track50, "acl": public-read, 
 "policy": wtLepKMeghI3rt1UeikLoQcNTYtMDktMTBUMTc6NDE6MTJaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJhY2wiOiAicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSwgeyJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiOiAibTRhIn0sIHsiYnVja2V0IjogImZ1eZEaJKYzeDgZwz3lOPtys5B0MigIwImv2OpQm3ylP==, 
 "Content-Type": m4a, 
 "AWSAccessKeyId": XXXXXXXXXXXX, 
 "X-Amz-Credential": AWSAccessKeyId/2016915/us-west-1/s3/aws4_request, 
 "X-Amz-Algorithm": AWS4-HMAC-SHA256]
```

The error I'm getting back:

```
response:<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8713ed7090> { URL: https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
    Date = "Fri, 16 Sep 2016 03:36:42 GMT";
    Server = AmazonS3;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "x-amz-id-2" = "rzvVE96GNdVadls1wGigWYVsyoowITSI9sqWuEQ2IYIYsPdlV8HDlKQa0APQjwJ3Yxikp9L1ozU=";
    "x-amz-request-id" = 196F566C41386F62;
} }
ErrorReason(code: -2, message: "http error code 400")
```

Code for setting up the request

```
protocol FileUpload: Requestable {
var fileURL: NSURL { get }
var mimeType: String { get }
var request: NSURLRequest { get }
}

extension FileUpload {
    var request: NSURLRequest {
        let URLString = "https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com"
        let URL = NSURL(string:URLString)
        let r = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL!)
        r.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
        r.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        r.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(params, boundary: boundary)
        return r
    }

    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData()

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fileURL.lastPathComponent!)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendData(data!)
        body.appendString("\r\n")
        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        return body
    }

    func handleResponse(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Result<Serialize> {
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        print("response:\(httpResponse)")

        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            do {
                let json: JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                return Serialize.instantiate(json)
            }
            catch {
                print("Error thrown.  Could not parse JSON: '\(error)'")
                return Result(error:ErrorReason(code: -1, message: "invalid json stream \(error)"))
            }
        }
        print("error under handle response")
        return Result(error:ErrorReason(code: -2, message: "http error code \(httpResponse.statusCode)"))
    }
    return Result(error: ErrorReason(code:-2, message: "Unable to reach server"))

}
```

Comment: did you set bucket policy and cors conf?

Comment: I did not.  What is cors conf?

Comment: I am writing an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You should set bucket policy and cors config like below;

1. Open your bucket and click Properties at right side.
2. Click permissions tab
3. check upload/delete permission
4. click Edit Bucket Policy button and write this

   ```
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
       "Sid": "AddPerm",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKET/*"
   }
   ]
   }
   ```
5. Click edit cors configuration button and write this lines

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
   ```

Comment: Ok looks like my cors config was already set up (its been a while since I've last done this).  But my Edit Bucket Policy was empty so I added what you wrote.  For `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKET/*"` should I write my bucket name in all caps?

Comment: this might have been a step in the right direction, but didn't solve the problem.